# How to truncate floating points imprecision in python

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, precision

I am writing a program for which it is important to compare and rank values in a date series. However, I am running into problems with the imprecision of floats

I am pulling these data from my SQL server that are both supposed to be 1.6. However, they turn out to be slightly different (see below). Therefore, when I use dataframe.rank(), it doesn't treat these two dates as the same rank, but rather ranks 01/02/2004 above 02/01/2005.

Anyone have any idea how to deal with this so that these two would end up on the same rank?

```
modelInputData.loc['01/02/2004',('Level','inflationCore','EUR')]
Out[126]: 1.6000000000000003

modelInputData.loc['02/01/2005',('Level','inflationCore','EUR')]
Out[127]: 1.6000000000000001
```

Comment: Python docs on issues and limitations of floating points: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html.

Comment: Sounds like floats are not the correct solution here. If calculations need to have arbitrary accuracy, use decimals, not floats:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal

Comment: Yes I am probably going to end up doing this. Thanks!

Comment: decimal.Decimal doesn't support converting a pandas Dataframe/Series (or any list-like object for that matter) unfortunately (or I cannot figure it out at least). I am going with multiplying the entire thing by 100 and converting to integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to do it as bankers do - use cents and integers instead of EUR/USD and float/decimal variables

either convert it to cents on the MySQL side or do it in pandas:

```
df['amount'] = round(df['amount']*100)
```

You'll have much less problems then

Comment: Please use `round` here; the direct use of `int` risks accidentally truncating values. E.g. `int(0.29 * 100)` -> `28`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, you are absolutely right, thank you for pointing that out! I've changed my answer

Answer (score 7):

You can use pd.Series.round() on the columns with floats.

```
precision = 2
df['col'] = df['col'].round(decimals = precision)
```

See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html

Comment: What if the numbers are smaller than whatever precision you pick?

Comment: The inaccuracy stays actually when you do this, but weirdly they are now the same(1.6000000000000001). In general though, rounding doesn't solve the inaccuracy problem

Comment: This is not the same as truncation; this will round negative numbers _away_ from zero, whereas truncation would round them _towards_ zero.