# Pandas is creating not existant extra digits in the end of a float number

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Let's consider the following simple csv file

```
end_beat
2.989583333
1.989583333
2.989583333
```

### Pandas Approach

When I try to use pandas to read this csv file with the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('debug.csv')
print(df['end_beat'][1])
```

I got

> 1.9895833330000001

### Python csv library approach

However, when I use another method to read the data, everything is fine

```
import csv

with open('debug.csv') as f:
    df = csv.DictReader(f)
    next(df)['end_beat']
    print(next(df)['end_beat'])
```

> 1.989583333

Only the result returned by pandas has this problem, how to get rid of the extra zeros?

Comment: @cs95 My question is how to fix it. The question you post is asking why. These are two completely different questions.

Comment: Once you understand why it is happening you either forget about it or ask a more informed question. Do you want to round? Truncate? "Get rid of it" is broad.

Comment: I know floating point arithmetic could cause this problem. If that post is asking `a=0.3` yields `a == 0.3 >> False`, then I agree that my post is a duplicate of that post. But there's no arithmetic involved in my question, it's just value copying here. I don't get why just copying the value could also cause this problem.

Comment: In any case, you'll find [this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319851/how-to-truncate-floating-points-imprecision-in-python). If you don't want rounding, you can apply `math.trunc`

Comment: There doesn't have to be arithmetic involved for floating point precision errors to occur -- the number just has to not have an exact binary representation.